# I did not install postgresql, so why do I have postgresql related binaries in 12.04?

Tags: postgresql

I am going to compile postgresql from source, but the system already has postgresql related binaries such as pg_config, which gives me a lot of environment variables etc when I run it. I did not install postgresql an I've double checked from software manager. 
Why do I have postgresql related files? They lead to problems when I try to develop extensions with the custom compiled version of postgresql since various environment variables have already been configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably some other installed package depends upon postgresql, so the binaries got pulled in.  You can run

```
apt-cache rdepends postgresql
```

to see all the reverse dependencies.